# Libserial read serial port

Tags: c++, libserial

I am using `libserial` library to interact with a modem using C++. The C++ code sends an AT command:

```
my_serial_stream << "AT+CSQ" << '\r' ;
```

The modem responds with a response, either `ERROR` or `OK`,

The c++ code to read the response:

```
while( serial_port.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0  ) 
{
    char next_byte;
    serial_port.get(next_byte);
    std::cerr << std::hex << (int)next_byte << " ";
} 
std::cerr << std::endl;
```

I would like to handle the response such that if the response is `OK`, the modem sends another command and if the response is `ERROR`, the modem resends the first command.

Comment: First of all, shouldn't you be sending `"\r\n"` as newline (it's usually the common newline, `'\r'` used alone was only used on old Macs)? Secondly, why not simple read a whole line from the serial port (using e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)), and just compare the text to `"OK"`?

Comment: The standard when sending to the modem is indeed `\r`, but the modem is expected to send `\r\n` when echoing. The terminal program will only ever generate a single character even for the return key, while the modem will try to go for a legible display.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Using `getline` could stop the thread when there is no modem connected or when it is in transparent data transfer mode. So farai should write "The modem responds with either `ERROR`, `OK`, or probably not at all."